# Adding new Window in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have javafx application with Multiscreen and everytime am overlaping new screen over the old screen but for one case i need to 2 screen as show in image:

[image]

But when do an click event viewresult window then new screen should add in another window.

Like : I have 2 window pane Analyze window and View result window pane if I do any click event on View results window then Analyze window should change to new window. Sample Code shared below:

ScreensController

```
public class ScreensController  extends StackPane {
    //Holds the screens to be displayed

    private HashMap<String, Node> screens = new HashMap<>();

    public ScreensController() {
        super();
    }

    //Add the screen to the collection
    public void addScreen(String name, Node screen) {
        System.out.println(" adding ");
        screens.put(name, screen);
        System.out.println("checking :"+screens.get(name));
    }

    //Returns the Node with the appropriate name
    public Node getScreen(String name) {
        return screens.get(name);
    }

    //Loads the fxml file, add the screen to the screens collection and
    //finally injects the screenPane to the controller.
    public boolean loadScreen(String name, String resource) {
        System.out.println("Name :"+name +" and Resources is :"+resource);
        try {

            FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resource));
            //System.out.println("2");
            Parent loadScreen = (Parent) myLoader.load();
           // System.out.println("3");
            ControlledScreen myScreenControler = ((ControlledScreen) myLoader.getController());
           // System.out.println("4");
            myScreenControler.setScreenParent(this);
           // System.out.println("5");
            addScreen(name, loadScreen);
           // System.out.println("6");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }

    //This method tries to displayed the screen with a predefined name.
    //First it makes sure the screen has been already loaded.  Then if there is more than
    //one screen the new screen is been added second, and then the current screen is removed.
    // If there isn't any screen being displayed, the new screen is just added to the root.
    public boolean setScreen(final String name) { 
        System.out.println("screen load :"+(name));
        if (screens.get(name) != null) {   //screen loaded
            final DoubleProperty opacity = opacityProperty();

            if (!getChildren().isEmpty()) {   //if there is more than one screen

                Timeline fade = new Timeline(
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0)),
                        new KeyFrame(new Duration(100), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                        getChildren().remove(0);                    //remove the displayed screen
                        getChildren().add(0, screens.get(name));     //add the screen
                        Timeline fadeIn = new Timeline(
                                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)),
                                new KeyFrame(new Duration(80), new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0)));
                        fadeIn.play();
                    }
                }, new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)));
                fade.play();

            } else {
                setOpacity(0.0);
                getChildren().add(screens.get(name));       //no one else been displayed, then just show
                Timeline fadeIn = new Timeline(
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)),
                        new KeyFrame(new Duration(2500), new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0)));
                fadeIn.play();
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("screen hasn't been loaded!!! \n");
            return false;
        }


        /*Node screenToRemove;
         if(screens.get(name) != null){   //screen loaded
         if(!getChildren().isEmpty()){    //if there is more than one screen
         getChildren().add(0, screens.get(name));     //add the screen
         screenToRemove = getChildren().get(1);
         getChildren().remove(1);                    //remove the displayed screen
         }else{
         getChildren().add(screens.get(name));       //no one else been displayed, then just show
         }
         return true;
         }else {
         System.out.println("screen hasn't been loaded!!! \n");
         return false;
         }*/
    }

    //This method will remove the screen with the given name from the collection of screens
    public boolean unloadScreen(String name) {
        if (screens.remove(name) == null) {
            System.out.println("Screen didn't exist");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

ViewResults

```
Class ViewResults{
@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewResults vr=new ViewResults();
        vr.formateviolationxml(ud.dirpath+"\\.sonar\\export\\violations.xml");
        vr.xmlprase();

           ObservableList obList = FXCollections.observableList(vr.getResList());
           resourcelist.getItems().clear();
           resourcelist.setItems(obList);

        //   metricstabview.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

           violationtabview.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override 
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        if (event.isPrimaryButtonDown() && event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                            System.out.println(violationtabview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                            ViolationData datamet=violationtabview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                            System.out.println("viol line :"+datamet.getLine());
                            System.out.println("passing control to source importer");
                            myController.loadScreen(Main.sourceImportID, Main.sourceImportFile);
                            myController.setScreen(Main.sourceImportID);

                        }
                    }
                });
    }}
```

Analyzer

```
class Analyzer {
@FXML
    public void ccapresultsmenu(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("entered view results");
        //myController.loadScreen(Main.sourceImportID, Main.sourceImportFile);
        // myController.setScreen(Main.sourceImportID);
        // myController.loadScreen(Main.viewResultsID, Main.viewResultsFile);
        // myController.setScreen(Main.viewResultsID);

         Group root = new Group();
            Stage stage = new Stage();

            AnchorPane frame;
            try {
                frame = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/cts/gto/ccap/ui/view/ViewResults.fxml"));
                 root.getChildren().add(frame);
                    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    stage.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }


}
```

Comment: Upload images to imgur then post the link.

Comment: I cant able to add image . Am getting error as " you need 10 reputation to post image" i duno what it means. Am new to this

Comment: Added Link for image

Comment: It means you don't have enough reputation points to post images in your question. But you can post links to the images, and a person with higher reputation can edit your question and embed the images if they are appropriate for the question. I recommend reading the information in the help center, it will save you a lot of down votes and other negative feedback in the future.